# Second notification is not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I try to create multiple notifications. If click on the notification, it will link
to another Activity. After following code, it's create two lines of notification.
But when I click to the first line of notification, it's not working.
Only second works.

```
for (int i = 0; i < missionName.size(); i++) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    final Notification notifyDetails = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
            "Mission Completed, Click Me!", System.currentTimeMillis());
    notifyDetails.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notifyDetails.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence contentTitle = missionName.get(i) + " is completed";
    CharSequence contentText = "Please click to view the mission";
    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MissionMap.class);
    notifyIntent.putExtra("missionName", missionName.get(i));
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ApplicationMenus.this,
            0, notifyIntent, android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText,
            intent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(i, notifyDetails);
}
```

So, please help me to find my mistake. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should create the PendingIntent with different request codes.
Change this:

```
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ApplicationMenus.this,
        0, notifyIntent, android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

To this:

```
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ApplicationMenus.this,
        i, notifyIntent, android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Note that I've changed the 2nd argument to your loop index (i) instead of 0.
Intents are not created if you use the same arguments but rather they use a previous intent with the same arguments.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: walking home early because of you thanks @incrediApp

Comment: Sleeping early because of you @incrediApp

Comment: @IncrediApp You are great!

Answer (score 2):

```
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;       

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder TSB = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    TSB.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

    TSB.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            TSB.getPendingIntent(
                    randomNumber,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );

    nb.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```